# How do I train my LSTM on 1-dimensional sequences?

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to train an **LSTM** using sentences that were previously encoded as vectors. What I want to do is to use the **LSTM** layer to map a question to an answer.

Now, I get the input shape for the **LSTM** using `X_list[0].shape`, but Keras expects `X_list` to be three-dimensional.

Here is my code:

```
questions = [question.ljust(maxLenQs) for question in question]
question_ngram = n_gram.ngramStrings(questions,2)
print("Finished getting the ngrams.")
X_list = np.array(question_ngram)
print("Type of X_list: " + str(X_list.dtype))
maxLenAs = max([len(answer) for answer in answers])
Y_list = [answer.ljust(maxLenAs) for answer in answers]
Y_list = [answer.split(" ") for answer in Y_list]
vocabulary = set()
print("Beginning one-hot encoding.")
from keras.preprocessing import text
Y_list = np.array([text.one_hot(answer,len(vocabulary)) for answer in answers])
print("Finished one-hot encoding.")
# Expected number of dimensions: 2
# import sklearn.preprocessing
assertionMessage = "Assertion failed: X_list: " + str(len(X_list)) + " Y_list " + str(len(Y_list))
assert len(X_list) > 0, assertionMessage
print("Building neural network")
# Define our neural network.
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,LSTM,Dropout
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
model = Sequential()
# Train our model.
# Each X represents columns (is our X this word/that word?) 
# Each X includes one word from the answer (or None if we're talking about the first word)
# Train our model.
# Each X represents columns (is our X this word/that word?) 
# Each X includes one word from the answer (or None if we're talking about the first word)
dimensions = 100
print("Loaded model")
model.add(LSTM(100,input_shape=X_list[0].shape,return_sequences=True))
print("X list shape: ",X_list.shape)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your data's into three dimension

For example, if you have data of shape `(1000,3250)` i.e you have 1000 samples of 1D array of size 3250. You can reshape into `(1000,1,3250)` and train your model in it. You can use numpy to resize your data

```
import numpy as np
data = np.resize(data,(data.shape[0],1,data.shape[1]))
```

Comment: So, confusingly, I've resized my X_list and now I have a 3-dimensional shape. However, Keras is now complaining that my input is 4-dimensional.

Comment: did you change the input_shape parameter in the first layer. if not set it as `input_shape=X_list.shape[1:]`

Comment: Well, yes - but your code seems to have resolved the ValueError.

Comment: Can lstm be used for one dimensional data for regression problem?